# Poorman's shunt theory

Tags: high-current, shunt

#### Background

I'm doing a DIY project of bulding a 1kW Induction heater.
in the process I have built a poormans PSU out of a MOT ( and a 50V 25A brigde rectifier. with not even nearly enough of a smoothing cap (2,500 uF from a broken switched psu for my old comp).. but anyway:

#### Method

I am going to build a Volt/Amp-meter with a Aurdino tiny and as I am testing my prototype something is a bit of..

I'm just wondering what I'm doing wrong..

According to the internet copper has a resistivity coefficient (q) of \$1.72\cdot 10^{-8} =  q\$.
Resistance (R) in a conductor is given by \$(q L)/A =  R\$
where L is length in meter and A is Surface area in \$m^2\$.

The resistance I'm using for a shunt is a 2.5mm^2 copper cable (European way. I don't know gauge)

now, I decided I want 2mV/A in drop and that, witch all other variables now given gives me a Length (L) of 0.727 m for a

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLs3t4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Issue**
When I hook it up to a known circuit that handles 20A+ and go to calibrate it in reference to my multimeter I end up at 5.7mV/A drop instead of 2.0mV/A witch was calculated.

It's quite a difference and since this stuff is pretty straightforward \$U=RI\$ I wonder what I'm missing?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail exactly how you connect to the shunt? The circuit diagram above shows the voltmeter connected on the *circuit* side of the resistor terminals, so you're measuring voltage drop on the connections and also the shunt. It would be easy to have a few mOhm there. Better to connect the shunt to the circuit, and then a short way from the ends of the wire, clamp on your sense terminals. Also describe how the Arduino is powered and if its ground is common with anything else?

Comment: Yes thanks, forgot about that, i shopuld connect it to the return path as close to the end as possible.. And i havent connected it to my tiny yet, i just tried it on low amp with my multimeter and osc as reference

Comment: [Here is a recent answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/178993/61670) with a nice diagram of the way to connect to a shunt. It shows all the parasitic resistances, you can easily see how they will affect your results if they're included in the measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A is not surface area it is cross-sectional area.

So L = \$\frac {A R}{\rho}\$ = 0.291m

A  = 2.5E-6 m^2

R  = 0.002\$\Omega\$

\$\rho\$ = 1.72E-8 \$\Omega\$ m (your number)

You're right, it's a lot easier (from first principles) using European units rather than gauges, but usually we just look it up in a [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge).

Copper has a quite high temperature coefficient  (about +4000 ppm/K) so it's only useful as a crude shunt. Even brass is better, but nichrome constantan or manganin would best (in order of possible difficulty to source).

Comment: hrmm.. my actual misstake i see now was that i took 
A=.0025^2=6.25E^-6
i meant cross-sectional area.